# GEO IP block in IPFW on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ipfw

I would like to start blocking specific countries from accessing my servers. Are there any tools or scripts that can set up a GEO IP block list to inject into IPFW as rules?

I've seen a few references to this tool ipdb, but it hasn't been updated in a few years. https://github.com/cyclaero/ipdb

I have a script that downloads a list of IP addresses already that can create rules for botnets, so I'm more concerned with getting a list of IP addresses that's current and updated for country blocks more than the details of setting up IPFW.  My script is here https://github.com/MidnightBSD/mports/blob/master/security/blocklist-de-all/files/blocklist.sh

Answer (score 1):

The ipdb tool is working as expected. One has to periodically run the ipdb-update.sh to fetch the current ips.

Then setup a script like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/ipup -t RU:KP:IR -n 6 | /sbin/ipfw -q /dev/stdin
/sbin/ipfw -q add 915 allow tcp from not table\(6\) to any 80,443,21,20 in recv ix0 setup
```